# SQL Server - sort timestamp date field in sub query then format for viewing

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have a query (SQL Server 2012) that combines UNIX timestamps from two different tables into one column, which on its own works fine. The query needs to be sorted (descending) by the combined date column AND converted into a readable format.

If I attempt to sort after the date has been converted, it doesn't work as it is now a VARCHAR and returns:

```
05/02/2018
06/01/2017
07/03/2016
```

First I tried including a date conversion in the ORDER BY clause but that clearly doesn't work.

I then thought I could use a subquery to perform the sort then do the conversion in the main query (see below for what I currently have), but this is returning the error:

**Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.**

I'm not using a fetch statement, so I'm wondering if there's something in my nesting that SQL Server doesn't like.

Any clues would be terrific.

```
-- Convert Epoch timestamp format to readable (and unsortable) dd/MM/yyyy format
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(second, OuterTable.thedate-DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 103)), 103) AS FinalDate
  FROM (

 -- Subquery only exists to do a proper date sort
 SELECT thedate
   FROM 
   (
       SELECT 

        -- Determine which date to use
         CASE WHEN x.dateX IS NOT NULL
              THEN x.dateX
              ELSE y.dateY
              END AS thedate

        -- Get date from first table
         FROM (
             SELECT id, dateX -- date is in Epoch format (BIGINT)
               FROM tableX
         ) AS x

        -- Get date from second table
         JOIN (
             SELECT id, dateY -- date is in Epoch format (BIGINT)
               FROM tableY
         ) AS y
         ON x.id = y.id
   )

-- Perform sort while date is still in epoch format
ORDER BY thedate DESC

) AS OuterTable
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO this should work for you:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(second, COALESCE(x.dateX, y.dateY) - DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 103)), 103) AS FinalDate
FROM tableX AS x
INNER JOIN tableY AS y
ON x.id = y.id
ORDER BY COALESCE(x.dateX, y.dateY) DESC;
```

Not sure when copy/paste the `CONVERT` function. Is it so complicated to convert epoch to dd/MM/yyyy in MSSQL?

Comment: Yeah it's a doozie alright. I've inherited the report from someone else and that's how the dates have been converted. Haven't really looked at simplifying (aside from using SQL's FORMAT function).

Will give coalesce a shot - thank you!